# JavaFX ClassNotFoundException when running from command line

Tags: java, javafx

I've recently upgraded from Java 8 to Java 14. Also, I just downloaded an app that uses JavaFX. When I run the app from the command line, I get the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.browser.GlyphsBrowserApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I have already installed OpenJFX 14, but some of the installations seemed vague.

Here's how I installed OpenJFX so far:

```
(User Variables)

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2

JAVAFX_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib

(System variables)

Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-140.0.2\bin

PATH_TO_FX: C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I've been looking through here and YouTube for a couple of hours but I haven't found anything.

If you could help, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the command you used to launch the application.

Comment: I opened command prompt in the directory where the file was located and I ran the following command: `java -jar fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar `

Comment: Try `java -p <path-to-javafx> --add--modules javafx.controls -jar fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar` where "<path-to-javafx>" is replaced with the real path.

Comment: When you say <path-to-javafx>, do you mean the path to the root directory or the lib folder?

EDIT: I tried the following command:
`java -p "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add--modules javafx.controls -jar fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser-all-1.0.jar `                                                        
and it gave me the following error:

`Unrecognized option: --add--modules
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. `

Comment: `--add-modules`, not `--add--modules`.

Comment: I got the application to run, but now I'm facing a long error message. Check the link to see it. https://pastebin.com/FQaUsapR

Comment: That's really a new question, but there is indeed no such class as `com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CssParser` in JavaFX 14; it was moved to `javafx.css.CssParser`. Is `de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon` your class, or from a library you are using? If it's yours, you need to update your code to use the proper class (you always risk these errors on updating the JDK/JavaFX if you use non-public API). If a library, you need a JavaFX14 compatible version of the library.

Comment: It's a library. I think the source code is available, so should I create a project in JavaFX 14 and fix the imports?

Comment: Assuming [this project](https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser/) is the one you're trying to execute, it looks like there's a [couple issues](https://github.com/Jerady/fontawesomefx-glyphsbrowser/issues) with it on Java 9+. The project hasn't been updated since 2017. One option is to use JavaFX 8 when executing the project, but I don't know where to get JavaFX 8 standalone. Of course, you could instead try to fork the project, fix the issues, and build it yourself instead.

Comment: However, the actual [fontawesomefx library](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/master/) (as opposed to the sample project) appears to have versions compatible with more recent JavaFX releases.

Comment: The app that I was trying to launch was a browser that shows a list of the icons with enum values for each of them.